# RoR: Before filter returning false does not stop action form running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my test, I do this:

```
     delete :destroy, :id => p.id
     assert_equal "You do not have permission to delete this Object.", flash[:error]
     Object.find_by_id(p.id).should_not be_nil #line 48 (reffed by console output below)
```

and my before filter, has a puts, so I know the result is false, and doesn't return

```
  before_filter lambda { |controller| 
      result = controller.is_object_on_same_account_as_current_account_for_id?(
                  controller_name.classify.constantize, 
                  controller.params[:id])
      puts result
      return if result
  }, :only => [:destroy]
```

according to this page: http://citizen428.net/archives/846, actions bound by a filter are only executed if the filter returns.

And here is the console output:

```
Started
false
F
Finished in 0.865708 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test: .... ...
blah blah, issue is on line 48

     shoulda (2.11.3) lib/shoulda/context.rb:382:in `...']:
expected: not nil
     got: nil
```

So... what is going on here? I'm completely clueless.

related code:

destroy method:

```
 def destroy
    @content.destroy
```

Not, that I'm only running the one test.

Comment: Point out the code which is failing, and provide more *details*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the official [Rails Docs](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html), the proper way to stop an action from being executed with a `before_filter` is to actually redirect or render within the filter.

So you'd probably want:

```
before_filter lambda { |controller| 
      result = controller.is_object_on_same_account_as_current_account_for_id?(
                  controller_name.classify.constantize, 
                  controller.params[:id])
      puts result
      if !result
        flash[:error] = "You do not have permission to delete this Object."
        redirect_to "/" # or wherever you want to redirect to
      end
  }, :only => [:destroy]
```

Comment: what if my app uses ajax pretty heavily, and doesn't do too much along the lines of redirection?

Anywho, I tried added a redirect_to in there... and it says that it's undefined. I'm using rails 2.3.8

Comment: @DerNalia - It looks like you'd need to use `controller.redirect_to`, since you're inside that lambda.  There's also the [head](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000466) method, which might work better with your AJAX.  Cheers!

Comment: When I do controller. , I get this: NoMethodError: protected method `redirect_to' called

Comment: It's recomended to use a separate method for each filter: `before_filter :check_whatever; def check_whatever...`

Comment: the goal was to use a simple before_filter on all of my controllers for which I want to block the destroy method in certain scenarios. Is there still a way to do that? cause I hate duplicate code.

Comment: @DerNalia Put the `before_filter` function in `ApplicationController`? Not sure if that would work.